# How to give only 'n'(say 3) colors randomly to scatterplot points in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, scatter3d

Generated random numbers x,y,z, then put them in scatter 3d plot but am unable to plot the points, randomly with 3 specific colors (say red,black,yellow).

In documentation of [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), I am unable to understand the other 3 ways of specifying colors except the 1st one.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

x, y, z = np.random.rand(3,50)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,marker='.',color='b')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to randomly assign color to each point from set of n colors, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

x, y, z = np.random.rand(3,50)
n=3
colors = np.random.randint(n, size=x.shape[0])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,marker='.',c=colors)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the 3 points of documentation :The marker color. Possible values:

A single color format string.
A sequence of color specifications of length n.
A sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.

Comment: and if you want to specify the color palette, replace the `colors` array definition with: `colors = np.random.choice(['red','black','yellow'], size=x.shape[0])`

Comment: thanks that works ! can't accept before 8 minutes !

Comment: as to your question on documentation of c argument: 1st option is just one color, e.g. 'red' - all points will be red. 2nd point - list of colors, e.g. ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'red', ...] - one color per point. Number of the data points must match the length of the c array (this approach is used in the command given in the comment). 3rd point - you pass numbers, that are mapped to scale (from 0 to 1, I believe) - `matplotlib` has number of colormaps that just map number to color (e.g. from black to white, from blue to red through purple etc.). 4th point - you give RGB values, 3 per each point